# Add new row when cell value changes

Tags: vba, excel

I need to add a new row whenever a cell values changes in a defined column. I then need it to do the same for another column, then another column after that.

I used the same code three times, with different columns referenced, but I think it is not working due to the new (blank) rows entered from the first run. I've written it as three separate `Subs`.

```
Sub LineTestCODE()

Dim lRow As Long
For lRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
    If Cells(lRow, "C") <> Cells(lRow - 1, "C") Then Rows(lRow).EntireRow.Insert
Next lRow    

End Sub


Sub LineTestENHANCEMENT()

Dim lRow2 As Long
For lRow2 = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
    If Cells(lRow2, "D") <> Cells(lRow2 - 1, "D") Then Rows(lRow2).EntireRow.Insert
Next lRow2

End Sub


Sub LineTestZONE()

Dim lRow3 As Long
For lRow3 = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
    If Cells(lRow3, "G") <> Cells(lRow3 - 1, "G") Then Rows(lRow3).EntireRow.Insert
Next lRow3   

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure how you want to add your rows. It looks as if you want to test the changed cell and if it doesn't match the cell above add a row. I guess it's also possible that you want to add one row per unmatching cell pair in your columns. You'll see both in the code below - take your pick.

I put this code in the Sheet_Change event but you could put it in a module and call it from this event if you wished. You'll see I've disabled events, this could be the problem with your code.

This routine doesn't test if someone pasted values (ie Target.Cells.Count > 1). You might want to handle the possibility of Target being multiple cells.

```
For Each item in Target.Cells
    ..//..
Next
```

could work for you.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim MyColumns As Range

    ' Define the value columns we're interested in
    If MyColumns Is Nothing Then
        Set MyColumns = Union(Columns("C"), _
                              Columns("D"), _
                              Columns("G"))
    End If

    ' If you just want to add one row for a non-matching change in one of the three columns changes
    If Not Intersect(Target, MyColumns) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Row > 1 Then
            If Target.Offset(-1).Value <> Target.Value Then
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                Target.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        End If
    End If

    ' If you want to add one row for each non-matching cell value in the three columns
    Dim cell As Range

    If Not Intersect(Target, MyColumns) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Row > 1 Then
            For Each cell In Intersect(MyColumns, Target.EntireRow).Cells
                If cell.Offset(-1).Value <> cell.Value Then
                    Application.EnableEvents = False
                    cell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
                    Application.EnableEvents = True
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```